# Are kosher foods considered to be halal?

Tags: halal-haram, food

If kosher foods contain no alcohol within them, is it safe for a Muslim to consume kosher?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Islam (Sunni Point of view), eating the meat of Ahl Al-Kitaab (Jews and Christians) is permissible (Halal). However, whoever leaves it out of piety, there is no blame upon him.

> Yes, eating the poultry is permissible because that which is
>   slaughtered by the Ahl Al-Kitaab today is just as what was slaughtered
>   by Ahl Al-Kitaab in the time of the Prophet (sallallaahu ’alayhi wa
>   sallam). The Ahl Al-Kitaab are of the Kuffaar (disbelievers) whether
>   they are in the time of the Prophet (sallallaahu ’alayhi wa sallam) or
>   now. Allah says in His Noble Book They have certainly disbelieved who
>   say that Verily Allah is Isa Ibn Maryam and the Messiah said “O
>   Children of Israel worship Allah my Lord and your Lord Verily
>   whosoever commits shirk (associates partners with Allah in any way)
>   Allah has made the Paradise forbidden to him and his end will be the
>   Hellfire and there will be no help to the Dhaalimeen. They have
>   certainly disbelieved who say that Allah is the third of three and
>   there is no deity except the single Deity and if they do not desist
>   from what they are saying We will inflict upon those disbelievers a
>   painful punishment.
>
> Allah also says in the same chapter: “Today I have made permissible
>   for you that which is good and wholesome and the food of those who
>   were sent the Scripture is permissible to you and your food is
>   permissible to them.”
>
> As far as the methodology of the slaughtering we do not inquire about
>   the method because if an action has occurred min ahlihi [at the hands
>   of those suited to perform such an act] the conditions surrounding
>   that act are not asked about.
>
> We find in Saheeh Al-Bukhari: “It is related by Aisha (radhi Allaahu
>   anha) that a group of people said to the Prophet (sallallaahu ’alayhi
>   wa sallam) ‘Some people came to us with some meat about which we
>   didn’t know whether the name of Allah was mentioned over or not’ and
>   he replied (sallallaahu ’alayhi wa sallam) Sammoo [Say the name of
>   Allah] over it yourselves and then eat. She [Aisha - radhi Allaahu
>   anha] said that these people had just recently been from the Kuffaar
>   [i.e. just became Muslim and the question was not asked as to the
>   method of slaughter].
>
> This rule therefore applies to the Jews and the Christians about whom
>   we don’t know whether or not they have mentioned Allah’s name or not
>   because their slaughtered meat is halal [permissible] to us.

Source: [Eating the Meat of Ahl Al-Kitaab (Jews and Christians)](http://salaf-us-saalih.com/2012/06/15/eating-the-meat-of-ahl-al-kitaab-jews-and-christians/)

This is a fiqh question and what I am posting is the opinion of Imaam Ibn Uthaymeen (May Allah have mercy on him).

Comment: this answer is not related to question. question is not about eating meet slaughtered by Jews. question is about Kosher which is equivalent of Halal in Islam.

Comment: Halal doesn't mean "Islamic Slaughtering", It means "Permissible" ([wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halal)). So, when the questioner asks if it is Halal, he/she is not asking about the method of slaughtering, rather he/she is asking the permissibility of consuming it. And considering that meat is a food, I answered.

Comment: I would like to add, all Kosher is not Halal. The reason is Kosher may contain alcohol. So to re-phrase "all non-alcoholic Kosher would be Halal"